# How to boost documents matching one of the query_string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Elasticsearch newbie here. I'm trying to lookup documents that has `foo` in its name but want to prioritize that ones having `bar` as well i.e. those with `bar` will be at the top of the list. The result doesn't have the ones with bar at the top. `boost` here doesn't seem to have any effect, likely I'm not understanding how boost works here. Appreciate any help here.

```
query: {
    bool: {
        should: [
            {
                query_string: {
                    query: `name:foo*bar*`,
                    boost: 5
                }
            },
            {
                query_string: {
                    query: `name:*foo*`,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Sample document structure:

```
{
    "name": "foos, one two three",
    "type": "car",
    "age": 10 
}
{
    "name": "foos, one two bar three",
    "type": "train",
    "age": 30 
}
```

Index mapping

```
{
    "detail": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "servings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add sample document

Comment: Hi Jaspreet - I have added sample document structure. Its not a real document. Those are too big to be included but the samples capture the field I am interested in and it is a top level field in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order for the query like so:

```
query: {
    bool: {
        should: [
            {
                query_string: {
                    query: `name:*foo*`,
                }
            },
            {
                query_string: {
                    query: `name:foo*bar*`,
                    boost: 5
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

it should work but if not you might need to do a nested search.

Comment: That had no effect, thanks though. Name is a top level field in the document why do it need a nested query?

Answer (score 0):

Search against keyword field.

If you will only run first part of the query ("query": "name:foo*bar*"), you will see that it is not returning anything. It is searching against tokens generated rather than whole string.
Text "foos, one two bar three"  generates tokens like ["foos","one","two","bar","three"] and query is searching for "foo*bar*" in individual tokens hence no result. Keyword fields are stored as it is so search is happening against entire text.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "name.keyword:foo*bar*",
                    "boost": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "name.keyword:*foo*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Wildcards take huge memory and don't scale well. So it is better to avoid it. If foo and bar appear at start of words , you can use prefix query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "bar"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also explore ngrams

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet. Query does not return any result once I include the keyword qualifier.

Comment: Can you add your mapping

Comment: Added mapping to the question.

Comment: @broun I checked with your mapping and  sample documents, I am getting desired result. Can you add an actual  value for name

Comment: Below are samples for name:

"Car, bar, yellow, with paint (Dummy)",
"Train, dried, blue, old"

Comment: @broun These both will not come . As in query either foo is being searched or document with both foo and bar

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. foo & bar were samples not in real doc. These are name from real doc. So consider foo -> Car/Train, bar -> bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236778/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-broun).

Comment: @broun. The reason docs are not appearing , I think is because of  "case" of searched text. Document  contains "Car" and you might be searching for "car". keyword texts are not analyzed so searched text should be exact.  To do case insensitive search normalizer needs to be  used. I can add example of that, If you can confirm  my  assumption is correct